# How to count a different mongodb schema from a parent schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

at the moment I have a tittle problem. I have a schema, where my blog post are stored. In anoter schema, I save the comments. In this schema I save the parent.id from the blog post.

Now, I want to count the comments, display this count under the blog post.
(Info: I use express, edge. All thinks works very well!)

My module looks like:

```
const Post = require('../database/models/Post');
const Comment = require('../database/models/Comment');


module.exports = async(req, res) => {
  const posts = await Post.find({}).sort({ _id: -1 });
  const estimate = await Post.count({}); //all post blogs  
  const comments = await Comment.count({}); //all comments

// here I want to count all comments from one post blog ... etc ...

res.render("index", {
    posts, estimate, comments
  });
}
```

Here are the schemas:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    content: String,
    username: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date()
    }
});
 
const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
 
module.exports = Post;

--------

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
 
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    comment: {
        type: String,
        //required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
    },
    parent_id: {        // <-- the _id from posts
        type: String
    }
});

var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
module.exports = Comment;
```

Hope someone can give me a hint.

Thanks

----------------------8<------------8<-------------------
EDIT:

My index.edge:

```
@each(post in posts)
 <!-- some code here -->

  {{ post._id }}   <-- current post id

  @if(post._id == allPostCommentCounts._id)
    have comments
  @else
    no comments
  @endif

  tried:
  @if(allPostCommentCounts.count > 0)
   have posts {{ allPostCommentCounts.count }}
  @endif

@endeach
```

The if statements doesn't work.

The console.log is the following from allPostCommentCounts and posts:

```
[
  { _id: '5f96c97a8cad2c5250597b0b', count: 2 },
  { _id: '5f9ee8fcfc7fb52de8c9ab50', count: 3 }
]

[
  {
    createdAt: 2020-11-01T16:55:49.139Z,
    _id: 5f9ee8fcfc7fb52de8c9ab50,
    username: 'f',
    title: 'f',
    description: '',
    content: 'fff',
    __v: 0
  },
  ...
  }
]
```

mmmhhh ... I don't know whats wrong.

Comment: res.render("index", {
    posts, estimate, comments, allPostCommentCount
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want the comment count of an specific post or all the post, so let's review each case.

#### Comment count of one post

This can be done by simply adding a query inside the count function specifying the blog id.

```
const commentCount = await Post.count({ parent_id: blog_id });
```

#### Comment count of all post

This one is a little more complex. You will need to use Mongo Aggregations (you can read more about them [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)). Basically you want to group your `Comments` by `parent_id` and count them, so here is how it should look like:

```
const allPostCommentCount = await Comment.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$parent_id",
    count: {
      $sum: 1,
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: the second one is what I need. But how can I get this results into my edge framework to disply the count's under each main blog post?

Comment: I got not experience with Edge but basically the result is an array with each object having this format: `{ _id: 24, count: 1 }` so basically when you go through your blog posts you just have to find the entry in the comment count list that match the specific id and display the `count` param.